# Grouping and Summing in SQL

Tags: sql, entity-framework

Good day

I would like to find out how I would Sort and group  the following data by grouping the Account and summing the grandTotal of the Account per Month.

This is my current Select statement:

```
SELECT 
    tbl_AccountLedger.ledgerName
    ,tbl_SalesMaster.date
    , tbl_SalesMaster.grandTotal

  FROM tbl_SalesMaster
  INNER JOIN tbl_AccountLedger ON tbl_SalesMaster.ledgerId =tbl_AccountLedger.ledgerId
```

Here is wat my select statement is bringing back

[image]

Now I need to sort this data by summing the grand total for each month for a legerName

Comment: Based on the use of `dbo` for the schema, I *assume* this is SQL Server, but I *hope* you haven't *really* called your database `C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\STERLINGBACKOFFICESUITE\STERLINGBACKOFFICE\DATA\1\STERLINGBACKOFFICEDB.MDF`...

Comment: You would use SUM, GROUP BY and ORDER BY. This is really the very basics of aggregation.  What have you tried that didn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the below query on SQL 2012 or higher version. I will suggest please read grouping in SQL.

```
SELECT 
tbl_AccountLedger.ledgerName
,DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(tbl_SalesMaster.date),MONTH(tbl_SalesMaster.date),1) AS Month
, SUM(tbl_SalesMaster.grandTotal) AS TotalGrandTotal
FROM tbl_SalesMaster
  INNER JOIN tbl_AccountLedger ON tbl_SalesMaster.ledgerId =tbl_AccountLedger.ledgerId
GROUP BY tbl_AccountLedger.ledgerName, DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(tbl_SalesMaster.date),MONTH(tbl_SalesMaster.date),1)
```